# Find and replace Dreamweaver - Adding a number each time?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I've just been doing some research about regular expressions on dreamweaver and had no idea you could do so much with find and replace.

One thing i haven't been able to figure out is if i have:

```
<div class="item active"> <img src="images/gates2/large/gates1.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">WG1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="item"><img src="images/gates2/large/gates2.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">WG1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="item"><img src="images/gates2/large/gates3.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">WG1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="item"><img src="images/gates2/large/gates4.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">WG1</div>
              </div>
```

Can i automatically change the 1 to 2, 3 ect? So it becomes an order? Rather than going through each manually?

Kind Regards,

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to do what you're describing using the Find & Replace method in Dreamweaver. I know this probably isn't the answer you want to hear but, you'll have to go through them manually. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.